# Enable REST service for CAS Apereo version cas-overlay-template-6.0

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I want to enable REST service for CAS Apereo version cas-overlay-template-6.0 (on Ubuntu 16.04)

I have done following this step:

Step 1: Add compile for REST API to build.gradle file

```
root@ubuntu16:~/cas-overlay-template-6.0# nano build.gradle
And add two line below under dependencies clock
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-rest:6.0.0"
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-rest-services:6.0.0"
```

[image]

Step 2: clean build

```
root@ubuntu16:~/cas-overlay-template-6.0# ./build.sh clean
```

[image]

Step 3: Build source code again

```
root@ubuntu16:~/cas-overlay-template-6.0# ./build.sh run
```

But in step 3, I got error like this.

```
CAS is configured to accept a static list of credentials for authentication. While this is generally    useful for demo purposes, it is STRONGLY recommended that you DISABLE this authentication method (by     setting 'cas.authn.accept.users' to a blank value) and switch to a mode that is more suitable for production.>
2019-12-30 01:17:55,465 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.support.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration] - <>
2019-12-30 01:17:55,806 INFO [org.apereo.cas.config.CasPersonDirectoryConfiguration] - <Found and added static attributes [[email]] to the list of candidate attribute repositories>
2019-12-30 01:17:59,004 WARN [org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplicationContext] - <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registeredServiceResourceRestController' defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/support/rest/config/RestServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apereo.cas.support.rest.RegisteredServiceResource]: Factory method 'registeredServiceResourceRestController' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: No attribute name is defined to enforce authorization when adding services via CAS REST APIs. This is likely due to misconfiguration in CAS settings where the attribute name definition is absent>
```

[image]
[image]

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this:

```
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-rest-services:6.0.0"
```

This module does this:

> Invoke CAS to register applications into its own service registry. The REST call must be authenticated using basic authentication where credentials are authenticated and accepted by the existing CAS authentication strategy, and furthermore the authenticated principal must be authorized with a pre-configured role/attribute name and value that is designated in the CAS configuration via the CAS properties. The body of the request must be the service definition that shall be registered in JSON format and of course, CAS must be configured to accept the particular service type defined in the body. The accepted media type for this request is application/json.

So you can remove it, if you don't need the functionality.

If you do need it, you will need to define attribute names/values that can enforce authorization as the error message is telling you.

> No attribute name is defined to enforce authorization when adding services via CAS REST APIs. This is likely due to misconfiguration in CAS settings where the attribute name definition is absent.

So, define:

```
# cas.rest.attributeName=
# cas.rest.attributeValue=
```

PS Don't add things you do not need.

Comment: @Mr Misagh Moayyed, Could you show me some guide clearly if I use REST JSON?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://fawnoos.com/2019/06/12/cas61x-rest-api/